extract generic argument type and replace with other
Assume you have a code, which cannot be changed:
type TProps<TK extends string, T> = { a: TK; b: T };


I need to make a wrapper type for it, which set TK at root, and T for field level:
type TWrap<TR> = {
  func: <T>() => TProps<TR, T>;
  otherFunc: <T>() => TOtherProps<TR, T>;
  ...
  // and many other type fields are omitted
}

wrapped to function, because ts cannot allow adding generic argument to type fields.
I tried to write code, but still cannot get solution (key rows are marked with comments 1 and 2):
type tf<R> = () => R;
type to<A1,A2> = {};

type TSetTypeArgument<T, A> = T extends tf<infer R>
    ? R extends to<infer X, infer Y> // 1
      ? to<X, A> & R                 // 2  
      : never
    : never;

type TRes = TSetTypeArgument<TWrap['func'], number>;

and test it:
const t3: TRes = { a: '', b: 7 };

// `b` must be number
const b = t3.b;
// but now `b` is `unknown`

It is possible TSetTypeArgument type to get variable b typed as number?
playground link
UPDATE:
Example of usage i am trying to archive:
application-api.ts
export type makeApplicationApi<TLocale, TState, TAction> = {
  form: <TForm>() => TProps<TLocale, TForm>;
  request: <TRequest>() => TOtherProps<TLocale, TRequest>;
  // ...
  selector: (state: TState, action: TAction) => string | number;
}

orders-api.ts

type TAppTypes = makeApplicationApi<TOrderLocale, TOrderState, TOrderAction>;

export type TOrderForm = TSetTypeArgument<TAppTypes['form'], TOrderFormsDictionary>;
export type TOrderRequest = TSetTypeArgument<TAppTypes['request'], TOrderRequestsDictionary>
export type TOrderSelector = TAppTypes['selector'];



UPDATE 2:
Question still not solved and required the solution

Does this do what you want? https://tsplay.dev/wXLdOw If so I can write up an answer.

Can you clarify or simplify the question? What is the expected outcome you are wanting?

@AlexWayne yes, but TSetTypeArgument should not refer TProps directly

If I am understanding this question correctly, you are looking to create wrapper for TProps that forces TK to be the same for each usage (TR/string) but allows you to specify the type of T as separate for each usage?
If that's the case, you have overcomplicated the type system. If TK is intended to stay static, define TK inside TWrap.
type TProps<TK extends string, T> = { a: TK; b: T };

type TWrap<T> = TProps<string, T>

This will give you
type TR = TWrap<number>;
const t3: TR = { a: '', b: 7 };

// is a number
const b = t3.b

If you're wanting to write types to magically infer the value of TR then that isn't possible within Typescript. Typescript needs to have something solid to infer off of somewhere in the type chain.
Here are some options if you want the type to be inferred at runtime:
// infer type from defined variable
type TWrap<T> = TProps<typeof defined-variable, T>

// infer type from another defined type
type TWrap<T> = TProps<another-type, T>

playground link

thank you for clarification. this approach is work and i am used it before in similar scenario, but these is different because i am want to 'call' wrapper once with shared for all nested field types type TR. func is alone there just for example, and in real code it have multiple fields. If i am start to up T to wrapper, it lost the reason and should contain full set of types each field.

I'm sorry, I don't understand what you're trying to achieve here. Could you post an example with more real inputs and the expected output?

It's not a problem, i am updated a question and usage example.
because of explanation (and many of experiments) i am started to understand that is wrong way and language limitation.. maybe it is need to start from scratch and use different approarch, but now i dont see the other way...
